# codigo em linguagem R

Tags: r, clusterização

Alguem consegue me explicar o que o codigo abaixo executa?

```
cluster <- ml_kmeans(variaveis_clusters_tratado, CODCLI ~ ., k = 5)                         
clusters <- ml_predict(cluster, variaveis_clusters_tratado)
```

Answer (score 0):

A linha `cluster <- ml_kmeans(variaveis_clusters_tratado, CODCLI ~ ., k = 5)` cria um modelo K-MEANS com os dados do dataset `variaveis_clusters_tratado`, seguindo a formula `CODCLI ~ .`, com 5 Clusters, isto é, `k=5`.

A linha `clusters <- ml_predict(cluster, variaveis_clusters_tratado)` tenta predizer os valores de `variaveis_clusters_tratado` usando o modelo que foi criado na primeira linha, isto é, o `clusters`.

Ao mesmo tempo em que faz isso, essa linha sobrepõe na memória do R o modelo criado. Isto é, ela usa o modelo e depois substitui ele com o resultado da predição, que provavelmente será um dataframe.

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda!!!